# Existing .so and .h files integration in android studio

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I have one shared library and one header file.
I did one sample project there I have generated .so and header files but now my problem is how to import existing .so and .h files in android studio.

I searched in google but there they are showing how to generate but I want how to import these files. Please suggest me some links or any other examples

Comment: It depends on how you are building the shared library that you load from your java/kotlin code. If you're using cmake you would add the prebuilt library [as a `SHARED IMPORTED` library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries). If you're using ndkBuild you would use [the `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` rule](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts). And of course the .so file should also be built using the NDK.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51418850/1524450) for a cmake example.

Comment: I am using android make I got that library from C developers and I just paste that library in myandroid src/libs directory

Answer (score 0):

> but now my problem is how to import existing .so and .h files in android studio

Usually, you should put your `.so` files inside `jniLibs` which is usually located at `app/src/main/jniLibs`, and put c/c++ source code inside `app/src/main/cpp`. See below directory structure.

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt // Your cmake configuration files. 
├── app.iml
├── build
├── build.gradle
├── libs
├── proguard-rules.pro
└── src
    ├── androidTest
    │   └── java
    ├── main
    │   ├── AndroidManifest.xml
    │   ├── cpp // Directory to put your jni native source code. 
    │   │   └── native-lib.cpp
    │   ├── java
    │   ├── jniLibs // Directory to put your jni libs, i.e. the .so files. 
    │   └── res
    └── test
        └── java
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52048933/8034839

Comment: I followed whatever you said , its done next i should do ndk-build or directly I should run the app.  where I should keep header file